# Details popup working, edit dialog not - in MVC 4 using Jquery UI

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've got a small MVC 4 application running (C# / Razor) and have no problem getting a jQuery popup for any rows returned in a dialog, when clicking on the "Details" link.
However, when clicking on the "Edit" link, I get a blank dialog. Any ideas?

I've searched and searched, but haven't found anything that works yet.
New to MVC also :(

JavaScript code here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
                $('.dialog-details').click(function () {
                    var url = $(this).attr('href');
                    var dialog = $('<div style="display:none"></div>').appendTo('body');
                    dialog.load(url, {},
                        function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                            dialog.dialog({
                                width: 1145,
                                height: 600,
                                modal: true,
                                title: "Reference Details",
                                close: function (event, ui) {
                                    dialog.remove();
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    return false;
                });
            });
    </script>
```

Razor syntax here: (first link works, second link displays a blank dialog)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ReferenceID }, new { @class = "dialog-details" })
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ReferenceID }, new { @class = "dialog-details" })
```

When the Edit link is used without the jQuery dialog class, it opens the page with all the information for editing - so controller looks fine.

Comment: What's happening on the server?  Your dialog is being populated by different URL's.  My guess is that one is working, and there's something wrong on the server with your Edit.

Comment: Hey Bob, controller seems fine. When I click on Edit without the jQuery class, it opens the Edit page fine.

Comment: What is the value of responseText?  Have you tried debugging with Fiddler?

Comment: Haven't tried fiddler yet nickels, good suggestion

Comment: Looks like it was not getting the validation token. I added it to the jquery load and it worked fine

Answer (score -1):

Please check your contoller and make sure that [HttpPost] used in your Edit() method